# I am attempting to select the correct radio button based on available information in an electronic medical record

Tags: javascript

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function EstimateBMR() {
     if ((document.getElementById("Age").value <= 30)&&(document.getElementById('PatientGender').value == 'M')){
           (document.FormName.EBMR[0].checked = true);
     }
     else if ((document.getElementById("Age").value  > 30)&&(document.getElementById("PatientGender").value == 'M')){
           (document.FormName.EBMR[1].checked = true);
     }
       else if ((document.getElementById("Age").value <= 30)&&(document.getElementById('PatientGender').value == 'F')){
           (document.FormName.EBMR[2].checked = true);
     }
        else if (document.getElementById("Age").value > 30)&&(document.getElementById('PatientGender').value == 'F')){
           (document.FormName.EBMR[3].checked = true);
     }
}
</script>
```

The relevant parts of the rest of the code are:

This code refers to several tables (oscarDB) to pull the values - I wish to use this information to select the appropriate category for the individual.

OSCAR is an opensource emr www.oscarcanada.org

```
<body onload=" EstimateBMR();">

<form method="post" action="" name="FormName" id="FormName" >

<input name="PatientGender" id="PatientGender" type="hidden" oscarDB=sex>

<td colspan=4 rowspan=3>Name:<input name="PtName" id="PtName" type="text" class="OscarFilled" style=" width:200px;"  oscarDB=first_last_name ><br>

DOB:<input name="DOB" id="DOB" type="text" class="OscarFilled"   oscarDB=DOBC ><br>

Age:<input name="Age" id="Age" type="text" class="OscarFilled"   oscarDB=age ></td>

<span style='background-color:lightgrey;'><b><u>Step 1 Estimate Basal Metabolic Rate</u></b></span>&#32;<input name="EBMRCalc" id="EBMRCalc" type="text" class="OscarFilled"  ><br>

<input type="radio" name="EBMR" value="0">&#9794; 18-30 =(0.063XActual Wt Kg+2.8957)X240Kcal&#47;d<br>

<input type="radio" name="EBMR" value="1">&#9794; 31-60 =(0.0484XActual Wt Kg+3.6534)X240Kcal&#47;d<br>

<input type="radio" name="EBMR" value="2">&#9792; 18-30 =(0.0621XActual Wt Kg+2.0357)X240Kcal&#47;d<br>

<input type="radio" name="EBMR" value="3">&#9792; 31-60 =(0.0342XActual Wt Kg+3.5377)X240Kcal&#47;d<br>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I have found my own answer - A missing opening bracket in this line:

    else if (document.getElementById("Age").value > 30)&&(document.getElementById('PatientGender').value == 'F')){
           (document.FormName.EBMR[3].checked = true);
     }

It needs to start else if (( document.getElementById("Age").value  ...

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own answer - A missing opening bracket in this line: else if (document.getElementById("Age").value > 30)&&(document.getElementById('PatientGender').value == 'F')){ (document.FormName.EBMR[3].checked = true); } It needs to start else if (( document.getElementById("Age").value ...